# working jQuery code won't run in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, local-storage, phonegap-build

Js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

        function onDeviceReady() {

            document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click",saveData,false);
            document.getElementById("btnShow").addEventListener("click",showData,false);
}

    function saveData(){
        var data  = window.localStorage.getItem("date");

        var dates = data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];

        dates.push( new Date() );

        window.localStorage.setItem("date", JSON.stringify(dates));

        alert("Your data is stored");
    }

    function showData() {
        var data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("date"));
        console.log(data);
        $('#res').html(JSON.stringify(data));
        $(this).html('Update result');
    }
```

html:

```
    <button id="btnSave"> Save Data </button>

    <button id="btnShow"> Show Data </button>
```

Code works in jsfiddle (someone provided it to me) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2uod274d/), I've edited it to integrate into phonegap, but the code now won't work when I run it in phonegap (Xcode simulator for iOS).

Comment: `won't work` - doesn't give us much to go by - do you have console errors you can share, any clue as to what isn't working would be smashing

Comment: there's no console errors. When I click Save data, no date gets stored in local storage, the alert "Your data is stored" is not displayed either.

Comment: is the page served http or https?

Comment: can you confirm that the code in `onDeviceReady` is ever called?

Comment: yes the code in onDeviceReady should be called as I have other codes in there that gets called without a problem.

Comment: I don't think http or https makes a difference? I've tried changing them around and it still won't work.

Comment: `I have other codes in there` just not in this example ... does the browser support localStorage?

Comment: I didn't put those codes in the example because it's not related, the simulator supports localstorage as I can store simple data (the ones that gets overwritten each time) into the localstorage without a problem.

Comment: `I don't think http or https makes a difference?` - well, if the page is served https, then in most browsers it will baulk at loading any http content (that's called mixed content)

Comment: I have tried changing both to http and to https but they didn't affect the outcome

Comment: I tried to debug your app on Andorid Studi but dont get any error. try looking at the further link on the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968831/using-local-storage-in-phone-gap

Comment: that link tells you how to first check whether that feature is working on the phone or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those elements may not be there when your `deviceReady` fired.So remove those lines from `deviceReady` and write like following:

```
$(document).on("click","#btnSave",function(){
    saveData();
});
$(document).on("click","#btnShow",function(){
    showData();
});
```

And use following `jQuery` and `jQueryMobile`

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed the lines from deviceReady and put in yours but it still doesn't work. This is getting so frustrated because I know the code works in normal windows html, but for some reason refuse to work in phonegap

Comment: Show your entire `html` page

Comment: I think those element should be called, because if I change my js to:         function saveData(){
            var date= new Date();
            window.localStorage.setItem("date", JSON.stringify(date));
            
            
            alert("Your data is stored");
        } so instead of saving multiple values, it overwrites the current date, and this works for me, but again this is not what I want the app to do.

Comment: I changed my answer.Check this

Comment: after i changed the jQuery and JQueryMobile versions, it gives an error: TypeError: dates.push is not a function. (In 'dates.push( new Date() )', 'dates.push' is undefined)

Comment: I just realise an error occurred in web inspector when I click on "Save Data": JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Sat"
, pointing to the line:
var dates = data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];

Comment: It is because your current data is mismatched with previous data.So remove your previous data by history clean .Or use `window.sessionStorage` instead of `window.localStorage`.Then previous data will automatically clear after you close the browser.