# Cordova/PhoneGap storage in native

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an app with Cordova/Phone Gap for Android and IOS. I have to save around 700-800MB in local. While the device does not have an internet connection, It should work offline saving data and when the device gets internet It will sent all the data to a server.

[I am reading that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005042/phonegap-offline-database) there are two options for big data:

1.- SQLite plugin
2.- Native storage

I am interested in native implementation but I can not find an example about how implement it.
Could anyone please provide me an example about how to implement native storage on Cordova/PhoneGap?

Comment: This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968831/using-local-storage-in-phone-gap

Comment: thanks but I mean native not local :)

Comment: Ok -- just clarifying: the app, while offline, will generate some 700-800MB of data, and when it gets back online needs to send that to your backend?

What kind of data are you saving? Structured data, images, documents, etc?

Comment: Yes that is correct, the data are : images, (custom)objects created in my app, double with locations, strings, integers....